# Ruby: toggle a boolean inline?

Tags: ruby

How can I get the opposite of a boolean in Ruby (I know that it is converted to 0/1) using a method inline?

say I have the given instance:

```
class Vote

  def return_opposite
    self.value
  end

end
```

Which obviously doesn't do anything, but I can't seem to find a method that is simple and short something like `opposite()` or the like. Does something like this exist and I'm just not looking at the right place in the docs? If one doesn't exist is there a really short ternary that would toggle it from 1 => 0 or 0 => 1?

Comment: welp.. It's a condition so I just used `!`

Comment: Was just about to post to that effect. If you want the opposite of `true` or `false`, you can't do much better.

Comment: Ruby has ternary expressions, right? If you want to be baroque you could say  `self.value ? false : true`. But I'd only code that to annoy someone ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I like to use this

```
@object.boolean = !@object.boolean
```

Answer (score 22):

#### Boolean expressions are not `0` or `1` in Ruby, actually, `0` is not `false`

If *n* is numeric we are swapping 0 and 1...

```
n == 0 ? 1 : 0 # or...
1 - n          # or...
[1, 0][n]      # or maybe [1, 0][n & 1] # or...
class Integer; def oh_1; self==0 ? 1:0; end; end; p [12.oh_1, 0.oh_1, 1.oh_1] # or...
n.succ % 2     # or...
n ^= 1
```

If *b* already makes sense as a Ruby true or false conditional, it's going to be hard to beat:

```
!b
```

These examples differ in how they treat out-of-range input...

Comment: Thanks for the input on the 0 != false... It was me being an idiot and looking at a record in my db, it seems active record writes it as 0

Answer (score 8):

You can use XOR operator (exclusive or)

```rb
a = true
a # => true
a ^= true
a # => false
a ^= true
a # => true
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: See comment by @philomory below.

---

I believe this is basically an oversight in the boolean classes (TrueClass and FalseClass) in Ruby.

You can negate any object:

```
nil.! => true
false.! => true
true.! => false
0.! => false
1.! => false
a.! => false (all other objects)
```

But you cannot in-place negate the boolean objects:

```
a.!! => does not compile
```

I guess this would call for trouble with the compiler's grammar.

The best you can do, is thus:

```
a = a.!
```

Comment: While it's true that `a.!!` is a syntax error, the reason is far deeper than just a grammar issue or an oversight in `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`. Variables are not objects and objects are not variables; variable _name_ objects (refer to them, hold them, however you want to term it), and the _only_ thing that changes the value of a variable within a given scope is an assignment. If `a.!!` couldn't ever be a re-assignment of a different object to `a`, it would have to be a mutation of the object that `a` names. But there is only one `true`, and it is immutable. (cont)

Comment: (cont) If you could mutate it, then `true.!!` would permanently change the meaning of `true` throughout the entire system.

In any case, the common idiom `!!a` doesn't parse as equivalent to `a.!!()`, it's equivalent to `a.!().!()`. But again, that *returns* a 'boolean' value, it doesn't *mutate* the receiver (at least, given any of the core class definitions of the `!` method; you could certainly make one that acts as a mutator for a custom class, but outside of certain overly clever DSLs it'd be extremely confusing behavior to encounter).

Comment: `1.!.!` compiles in 2.6.3

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to access the opposite of the value, use `!` as some people have said in the comments. If you want to actually change the value, that would be `bool_value = !bool_value`. Unless I've misunderstood your question. Which is quite possible.

Answer (score 2):

In order to toggle a boolean data in rails you can do this `vote.toggle!(:boolean)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle boolean (that is `false` and `true`) , that would be as simple as just use `!` as others has stated.

If you want to toggle between `0` and `1` , I can only think of something naive as below :)

```
def opposite
     op = {0=>1,1=>0}
     op[self.value]
end
```

Comment: For toggling between 0 and 1: op = 1 - op.  Or, if you think in bits, op ^= 1

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails app, I use this method to toggle a post between paused and active, so ! (not) is my preferred method.

```
def toggle
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  @post.update_attributes paused: !@post.paused?

  msg = @post.paused? ? 'The post is now paused.' : 'The post is now active.' 

  redirect_to :back, notice: msg
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a ternary can be interesting :

```
check = false
check == true ? check = false : check = true
```

Comment: Hey there! This question is regarding Ruby.

Comment: Hey, Yes, it's in ruby. I changed my variable name, maybe that's what made you think it was something else than ruby.

Comment: idiomatic Ruby would be `check = check ? true : false`